# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen Error with AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I am trying to open a CSV File stored in an AWS S3 using Rails Active Storage but am getting the below error message. I am able to upload and download files without issues but seems to be an issue with the code.

Error:

`No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`- then it has the AWS URL - if this is copied and then pasted in the browser, I am able to download the file.

Code:

```
url = @item.csv.url
csv_file = File.open(url)
@data = SmarterCSV.process( csv_file)
```

The following are at the top of my controller as well

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
```

Comment: Did you mean `URI.open()`?

Comment: @jordanm That was it - simple fix - thanks!